# Simultaneous Message Boxes

Tags: python, tkinter, wxpython, messagebox

So I have created an event driven program that is supposed to prompt users when triggered by the specific event handler with message dialogs. Is there any way to instantiate these message dialogs simultaneously in the event that they coincide?

```
################################################################################
# Create Listener ##############################################################
################################################################################

# listens to a local directory for files

watch = Watcher(LOCAL_DIRECTORY, callback)

# set the appropriate flags for a listener

watch.flags = FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_FILE_NAME

################################################################################
# Start Listener ###############################################################
################################################################################

watch.start()

################################################################################
################################################################################
################################################################################
```

Comment: sure ... it should just work ...

Comment: @JoranBeasley Is really doesn't. One has to close before the other opens.

Comment: if you provide no example ... how am I supposed to know what you are doing wrong ... see example below ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it should just work, consider the following

```
import wx

def handle(e):
    wx.MessageBox("Hello","world")

a = wx.App(redirect=False)
t = wx.Timer()
t.Bind(wx.EVT_TIMER,handle)
t.Start(3000)
f = wx.Frame(None)
a.MainLoop()
```

this will open the message box every 3 seconds regardless of the previous one being open...

#### [edit]

after further discussion I will make an assumtion that your event is one you must poll for ... you should put the polling logic in its own thread

```
def poll_data(data_callback):
    def check_new_event():
        if do_something_to_check():
           wx.CallAfter(data_callback) # this will cause the callback to be executed in the main thread (All gui updates *should* be done in the main thread)
    while True:
       check_new_event()
       sleep(1) # force thread to surrender control for a while

def on_callback(*args,**kwargs):
    wx.MessageBox("Some Message","Title")

def my_app():
    a= wx.App(redirect=False)
    f=wx.Frame(None)
    th = threading.Thread(target=poll_data,args=(on_callback,))
    th.start()
    a.MainLoop()
```

#### [edit 2]

after your edit I will make another assumption that your `watch` library blocks until callback returns ... just use `wx.Callafter` like follows

```
def old_callback(*args):
    wx.MessageBox("Whatever","blah")
def callback(*args):
    wx.CallAfter(old_callback,*args)

watch.bind(callback) # or however
```

this allows the callback to return and watch to continue listening ... regardless of a blocking dialog

#### [edit 3]

here is a complete example using watch library

```
import watcher,wx
a = wx.App(redirect=False)
TARGET_DIR="/py_exp/testing"
def real_callback(*args):
    wx.MessageBox(str(args),"QQQQ")
def callback(*args):
    wx.CallAfter(real_callback,*args)
w = watcher.Watcher(TARGET_DIR, callback)
w.flags = watcher.FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_FILE_NAME
w.start()
f = wx.Frame(None)
a.MainLoop()
```

then just add and remove files from the directory (note the new popups *might* popup behind the existing one...but if you move them you should see all of them)

Comment: that shouldnt matter ... if you provide your existing code maybe I can show you ...

Comment: you should edit your question ... if you just send it no one else benefits from the solution ... show how you are binding the event etc you dont need to post your full code ... just the bit you are using currently to trigger a dialog (and how its triggered(eg how do you recieve the event etc))

Comment: I made an assumption and edited answer ... maybe that will help you

Comment: ok well here is 3 ways you can do it ... so not really sure what else I can add without knowing more and seeing a small code example that I can copy paste that will demonstrate the issue...

Comment: hmmm ... whats the file watch library name?

Comment: It's called [`watcher`](https://bitbucket.org/briancurtin/watcher) but could I send it to you and explain? This is really odd.

Comment: Thank you! It worked. I think it was just the lack of a frame, which I presume is needed to bind events.

Comment: @MalikBrahimi I have told you many times not to ask to ask, if you are getting errors post the error you are getting  ... since I am not familliar with the error message "I am getting some errors using this technique" I probably cant help with that error message